# Display ListViewItem at Bottom

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a simple ListBox inside a SplitView pane with 4 ListBoxItems in it like this.

```
      <SplitView.Pane>
            <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="mListBox" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBoxItem Name="Landing_Page">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="&#xE10F;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Mainpage" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="Page1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="&#xE8D1;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Page1" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                    <ListBoxItem Name="Page2">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <TextBlock Text="&#xE774;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Page 2" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem Name="About">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="&#xE774;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="About the App" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
      </SplitView.Pane>
```

Now I want to display the About ListBoxItem at the Bottom of the SplitView Pane.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to keep your UI styled similar to what you have now, is just use a second ListBox and place it at the bottom (using a Grid).

```
<SplitView.Pane>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox SelectionChanged="TopListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="TopListBox" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBoxItem Name="Landing_Page">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE10F;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Mainpage" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Name="Page1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE8D1;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Page1" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem Name="Page2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE774;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Page 2" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>

        <ListBox SelectionChanged="BottomListBox_SelectionChanged" Name="BottomListBox" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBoxItem Name="About">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE774;" Width="16" Height="16" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="4,0,0,2" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="About the App" Margin="16,0,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</SplitView.Pane>
```

[image: Splitview]

Since I'm using `Height="*"` on the first row and `Auto` on the second, the bottom About button is always visible and the top list will scroll if too many items are in the list.

[image: Splitview with scroll]

One more thing to fix is the selected item, since you're now dealing with 2 `ListBox`es instead of 1.

```
private void TopListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BottomListBox.SelectedItem = null;
    TopListBox.SelectedItem = e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault();
}

private void BottomListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TopListBox.SelectedItem = null;
    BottomListBox.SelectedItem = e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault();
}
```